# Why is this plane indicating an altitude of 117,200 feet?

Tags: aircraft-performance, military

Looking at a plane tracker, I found something where the altitude is crazy high. Could it be a plane masking identity?

[image]

Comment: There is an AEROSTAR up right now on boarder of Canada at 50,300 ft. What can go over 100,000 ft?

Comment: a bad altimeter setting can go over 100,000 feet. unfortunately the registration and ICAO codes are cut off in the screenshot, so it's hard to go back and see.

Comment: @tedder42 Registration could be SU-BAV, which is an Egyptian military C130. Would be nice if we had a timestamp though.

Comment: @Chris I've seen Egyptian AF C130s with this exact issue many times, so I think you're absolutely correct

Comment: As an aside, this is why ATC has to verify a plane's altitude.  When the pilot with good phraseology reports, "four thousand climbing one two thousand," (or the pilot with bad phraseology reports "four for twelve"), ATC correlates what the pilot said their altitude is ("four thousand") with what the plane's transponder is telling ATC's radar that the altitude is.  If they don't match, there's a chance the reported altitude is incorrect for some reason, as with the plane in your question.

Comment: @Fattie Uh, no. That is *obviously* an Android screenshot.

Comment: I guessed this was about the Egyptian C-130s just from the title. I've seen them flying into BWI with my own eyes while they're reporting these erroneous altitudes. Whatever the failure is, it's not just a one-off - it happens with multiple different aircraft.

Comment: @nobody - you're perfectly right, thanks.  I'm so used to pointing out the "overwhelming iFone screenshot issue" on SE sites, I didn't think. Thanks for pointing out my mistake

Comment: What flight tracker are you using?

Answer (score 47):

Without knowing the details of the flight, it looks like one of the bits in the altitude transmission is set wrong. In the coding of altitiude, the transponder uses the so-called [Gillham code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gillham_code). This is a modified [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) which changes only one bit between successive values.

I suspect the D2 bit is driven by a cable which either has a loose connection or a break and is intermittently shorted to ground. In this specific case this would lead to an altitude of 8300 ft to be transmitted as 117200 ft.

The transponder sends altitude encoded in 12 bits, logically grouped in four groups of three bits: [D4,D2,D1] [A4,A2,A1], [B4,B2,B1] en [C4,C2,C1]. (The transmission sequence of bits is a different order then depicted). D4 is not used for altitude, 11 bits are sufficient.

8300 ft is coded as (0)**0**0 011 010 100, with D2 being the **bold** (MSB) bit. 117200 ft is (0)**1**0 011 010 100.

Comment: Interesting!, can you elaborate on how a short would cause an altitude of 8300 ft to become 117200 ft?

Comment: @ROIMaison 8300 ft is **0**00 1101 0100, with D2 being the leftmost (MSB) bit. 117200 ft is **1**00 1101 0100. The fact that the color coding of the track indicates jumps up and down makes me believe this is very likely correct answer. You can look more at gray codes on https://www.avionictools.com/graycalc.php

Comment: I've noticed this exact issue many times with Egyptian air force C130 flying over Europe, but I'm not sure if it's always the same aircraft.

Comment: Amazing domain knowledge !

Comment: I'm looking right now at SU-BKS doing the same thing intermittently so it's definitely not a specific-aircraft issue (maybe a manifacturing defect on the whole batch of transponders?). It's alternating between 104300ft and 21200ft, so it's again the leftmost bit that is changing

Answer (score 9):

The altitude record for a subsonic fixed wing aircraft is 76,000 ft (Perlan II).

It is not possible that both the altitude and the ground speed are correct.  Lots of things fly at that ground speed.  Without knowing anything about the flight, it's quite probable the altitude is wrong.

Comment: Is there any possible way a C130 could be flying at 117,200 ft?

Comment: @Someone No.  Everything about the design is wrong.

Comment: What was wrong with my edit then?

Comment: @Someone  Edits really aren't intended to be used to wordsmith somebody else's answer. When there's a typo in a post, sure. When a link can be added or updated, great. When the originator isn't a native English speaker and an edit can improve the readability of a question or answer, then yes. But "improving" somebody's choice of words, not so much. Which is why the original author retains the ability to reject edits. When one disagrees with an answer's content, the way to register that is a down-vote. But Stack Exchange doesn't use edits (the way Wikipedia does) to correct another's work.

Comment: @RalphJ - just to clarify for those of us who are newer, I don't think you meant that it is out of line to have a different opinion on wording, but that if it changes meaning even slightly it is best to discuss it in the comments rather than editing. And downvoting if I understand correctly is for disagreeing with the entire premise of the answer not just disagreeing with some of the specific wording. The exception would be community wikis which have a different methodology. At least that's how I understand it.

Comment: @StevePemberton Yes, exactly.

Comment: I don't necessarily mind the edit as I am not a professional, just an enthusiast in aviation especially anything military related. If it helps bring in more professionals then go for it.

Comment: On a lighter note imagine if ground control wasn't aware of such failures. Uhhhhh, this is ground control to Pilot. Uh huhhhh, Chad was just joshing ya about how high he last took his C-130 this morning. This is not Spaceforce. Reduce altitude ASAP. 